# Bash User Select Volume

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to make a script for macOS and in that the user needs to select the Volume the System is installed onto. Problem is the Volume name isn't working (Not a valid install). It currently looks like this,

```
# Ask the user what drive macOS is installed on
while [ ! -e /Volumes/$VOLUME/boot ]; do
     printf "\nPlease enter the name of the disk macOS is installed on (Leave blank to exit):\n"
     read VOLUME
     if [ -z $VOLUME ]; then #if no value was entered
         exit 1
     fi
     if [ -e /Volumes/$VOLUME/boot ]; then
         break
     else
         printf "\nNot a valid install!\n"
     fi
done
```

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show results of `ls -l /Volumes/*/boot`?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this. Changed this,

```
if [ -e /Volumes/$VOLUME/boot ]; then
```

To This,

```
if [ -e /Volumes/$VOLUME ]; then
```